# Is there a password for everything?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I started playing human revolution a while ago and I noticed you can almost always find a PDA or an e-mail with a password to the computer or terminal so you don't have to hack it.

Now sometimes there is no PDA or e-mail available. Do these machines with no information to the password really have none? Or is there a password for every single hackable device in this game even though you won't find what it might be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All computers have a valid password and all keypads have a valid keycode. You can find out what they are by reading the relevant wikia pages for [passwords](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Passwords_%28DX3%29) and [keycodes](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Keycodes_%28DX3%29).

Comment: Wow I didn't think they would actually put a password for every single computer^^