# Are some DE:HR keycodes unobtainable?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/150542/83499), all keypads should have a valid keycode, however, the wiki linked list one or two codes as "?" Why are those codes not listed? Are some keycodes in the game unobtainable?

Anyone have access to the game and can run check, maybe?

The codes missing (at the time of writing this) are:

- "East Apartment F2" in Detroit Downtown Apartments
- "Hengsha Streets (South)" in Hengsha City

Comment: You are asking for a completion of an incomplete wiki article, before we begin, are you sure that the wiki listing for locations is correct? For IGN's table of codes and locations, those two locations you mention do not exist.

Comment: I did not check whether the wiki was correct. Sounds like a fun little project, checking if every single keycode listed is correct. Will do that as soon as I get back to my PC. Nonetheless, the problem might just be as you mentioned, that the keypads don't even exist.

Comment: We're going to need a map... ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the developers side it would be good idea to make all codes accessible despite the chosen playstile,only reason to exclude some would be a practical joke or a mistake(which would be fixed by now).

Some codes are hard to figure and are borderline guessing,meaning they can't be actually found,they are subtly implied from surroundings.Other ones can only be found during certain events and later get locked out.

[This](http://ps3trophies.com/forums/deus-ex-human-revolution/3067-check-security-safe-codes-hidden-praxis-kits.html) site has those 2 code you mentioned listed,but again as it usually goes it misses some codes that wiki has.

The password for "Alice Gardens Basement" is marked with question mark on the wiki,and it isn't even mention on the site I linked,but after quick search another site pops up saying that password is [dnkyhoeT](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-14432-85252-1-0-1-0-tous-les-codes-des-ordis.htm)

The amount of the codes found online sounds promising,but props if someone manages to verify all of them.

Comment: Cheers. I will check the keycodes on my next run.